# Is there a support for xmlns:href i Iron Router (for Meteor)?

Tags: meteor, svg, hyperlink, iron-router, xml-namespaces

The support for `xmlns:href` on Iron Router seems to be missing. Because of this I'm unable to put up links for my svg files.

It gives an error

> path.replace is not a function

Comment: Same problem here on 1.0.9, although I'm not sure why the SVG link would make `replace` undefined.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I'm trying to add href to a rect and get the same error